# Return date from json ..error: org.json.JSONException: Value 2007-03-22 at release_date of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

Tags: android, json

Sorry if this has been discussed already but i could not find a proper solution for this. 
I'm trying to return the date from json. which is in the format as `"release_date": "2014-10-10"`

This is my model class:

```
public class SingleInfo {

    public SingleInfo(){

    }
    String overview , image ;
    int voteCount ,, releaseDate ;

    public SingleInfo(String overview , int voteCount , int releaseDate , String image){
        this.overview = overview;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image){
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getImage(){
        return image;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview){
        this.overview = overview;
    }
    public void setVoteCount(int voteCount){
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }
    public void setReleaseDate(int releaseDate){
        this.releaseDate= releaseDate;
    }
    public String getOverview(){
        return  overview;
    }
    public int getVoteCount(){
        return voteCount;
    }
    public int getReleaseDate(){
        return getReleaseDate();
    }


}
```

Below is the code by which am setting the text to the release `TextView`

```
   try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObject =       jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                SingleInfo s = new SingleInfo();
                                String iss = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + jsonObject.getString("backdrop_path") ;
                                s.setImage(iss);
                                   s.setReleaseDate(jsonObject.getInt("release_date");

                                s.setOverview(jsonObject.getString("overview"));
                                s.setVoteCount(jsonObject.getInt("vote_count"));

                                single.add(s);


                            }

                            SingleInfo singleInfo =         single.get(_currentPos); //position from previous activity

                         voteCount.setText(singleInfo.getVoteCount());
                            release.setText(String.valueOf(singleinfo.getReleaseDate());



                                    overview.setText(singleInfo.getOverview()); */

                            vote.setText(String.valueOf(singleInfo.getVoteCount()));
                            imageView.setImageUrl(singleInfo.getImage() , imageLoader);




                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Everything is working fine except release date is not getting displayed. log says ..cannot be converted to java.lang.string

Comment: Does this even compile? Because given `setReleaseDate(int releaseDate)`, `s.setReleaseDate(jsonObject.getString("release_date"));` is clearly a type mismatch. (`int`vs `String`)

Comment: Hey sorry. That's typo. Must be getInt() ..but its not working still

Comment: It seems that you are not closing the bracket {s.setReleaseDate(jsonObject.getString("release_date");}.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the error to your question. You might also want to reconsider using an `int` for a date (and use a `java.util.Date`)

Comment: You mean using a SimpleDateFormat ?  Can you give me an example.

Comment: this is the error: 

`org.json.JSONException: Value 2007-03-22 at release_date of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to int`

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in you code:

```
int voteCount ,, releaseDate ;
```

It should be:

```
int voteCount, releaseDate;
```

Second typo:

```
s.setReleaseDate(jsonObject.getString("release_date");
```

It should be:

```
s.setReleaseDate(jsonObject.getString("release_date"));
```

But, those are not the only errors, at least not the important ones, I guess. There seems to be some logical errors:

`jsonObject.getString("release_date")` would return a `String`. So, you should change your class's signature like this:

```
String releaseDate;

public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

public String getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}
```

Comment: Dont mind the typo. It compiles fine. It was an issue with me copying. And it's getInt ..I edited it

Comment: But I don't think date will be returned in the form of int. It will be returned in the form of a String. So you should modify your class as I showed in the code. You might need to parse the returned date string or may be you could just create a native Date object with a string constructor, if one exists.

Comment: Yeah exactly. I tried with the SimpleDateFormat but there was a incompatible types. Could you pls guide me on this

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int, int, int)

Comment: just parse your string on "-" and you will get year, month and day. they will be in the form of String. Convert them into int and pass them into the constructor of GeorgianCalender in the above link.